# Variable number of inputs in a bash dialog inputbox

Tags: bash, forms, dialog

I'm trying to create a Bash dialog form that has a variable number of input fields. This code, for example, is a static one that allows four pieces of information to be entered:

```
exec 3>&1
VALUES=$(dialog --ok-label "Submit" \
      --backtitle "Test input form" \
      --title " Type information in " \
      --form "" 12 95 0 \
"Item 1  :"     1 1    "$Item1"   1  15 65 256 "Item 2  :"     2 1    "$Item2"   2  15 65 256 "Item 3  :"     3 1    "$Item3"   3  15 65 256 "Item 4  :"     4 1    "$Item4"   4  15 65 256 \
2>&1 1>&3)
exec 3>&-
```

That works fine. So now I thought I'd try this:

```
ITEMS=4; unset ITEMSTRING
for ((i=1; i<=$ITEMS; i++))
do
   ITEMSTRING=$ITEMSTRING"\"Item $i  :\"     $i 1    \"\$Item$i\"   $i  15 65 256 "
done
ITEMSTRING="$ITEMSTRING\\"
echo -e "$ITEMSTRING"
```

...which outputs this string:
 `"Item 1  :"     1 1    "$Item1"   1  15 65 256 "Item 2  :"     2 1    "$Item2"   2  15 65 256 "Item 3  :"     3 1    "$Item3"   3  15 65 256 "Item 4  :"     4 1    "$Item4"   4  15 65 256 \`

That string is identical to the one contained within the dialog script from before, so I thought I'd be able to do this:

```
exec 3>&1
VALUES=$(dialog --ok-label "Submit" \
      --backtitle "Test input form" \
      --title " Type information in " \
      --form "" 12 95 0 \
$ITEMSTRING
2>&1 1>&3)
exec 3>&-
```

But that simply produces the error: "**Expected 8 arguments, found extra 1.**" I tried double-quoting the $ITEMSTRING variable: "**Expected at least 20 tokens for --form, have 5.**"

Is it possible to construct a dialog command dynamically in this sort of way? What can I try to get the ITEMSTRING variable to be interpreted as the text it actually contains?

The aim, obviously, is to be able to alter the value of ITEMS and thus construct a user input dialog that has 4, or 6, or 19 user input fields, depending on context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm ... not quite sure how to get the string interpreted properly in this case ... an interesting problem in itself ...

But in general, when I want to pass arguments in this manner, some of which may be 'strings with spaces', the most reliable way is to capture each argument in an array, and then explode the array at the point of need.

This worked for me:

```
#!/bin/bash


Item1="one"
Item2="two"
Item3="three"
Item4="four"

ITEMS=4;
unset ITEMSTRING
declare -a ITEMSTRING
for ((i=1; i<=$ITEMS; i++))
do
   ITEMSTRING[${#ITEMSTRING[@]}]="Item $i  :"
   ITEMSTRING[${#ITEMSTRING[@]}]="$i"
   ITEMSTRING[${#ITEMSTRING[@]}]=1
   REF="Item$i"
   ITEMSTRING[${#ITEMSTRING[@]}]="${!REF}"
   ITEMSTRING[${#ITEMSTRING[@]}]="$i"
   ITEMSTRING[${#ITEMSTRING[@]}]=15
   ITEMSTRING[${#ITEMSTRING[@]}]=65
   ITEMSTRING[${#ITEMSTRING[@]}]=256
done

exec 3>&1
VALUES=$( 2>&1 1>&3 dialog --ok-label "Submit" \
      --backtitle "Test input form" \
      --title " Type information in " \
      --form "" 12 95 0 \
      "${ITEMSTRING[@]}"
)
exec 3>&-
```

Comment: Wow. The fact you've proved a dynamically-derived input form is possible is rather wonderful! Thank you. I will happily live with this re-write :) Also, I hadn't really thought about the fact that part of my strings had spaces: the array approach seems inevitable when you stop to consider that.

Comment: It's simpler to do `ITEMSTRING+=("Item $i  :" "$i" 1 "${!REF}" "$i" 15 65 256)`

Comment: @Philippe oooh, I had no idea arrays could be "+=" 'd like that too. I always did stuff like `A=( "${A[@]}" "new" "elements" "..." )`. Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: Could you explain what the ${!REF} syntax is doing, please? I *think* it's Bash indirect parameter expansion, but I am having difficulty wrapping my head around how it works and how I could get some text into it. Suppose I want the words 'First Item', 'Second Item' and so on to appear on the dialog field inputs: I think the "${!REF} bit is where that would happen, but I don't quite see how to set it to variable text like that.

Comment: Answering my own question in one sense. Imagine a folder of text files: I want the form to display as many inputs as there are text files, but also to display the current first lines in each file discovered:

`ls *.txt | sort > "txtlist.txt"
for ((i=1; i<=$ITEMS; i++)); do
  THISTEXT=$(sed "${i}q;d" "txtlist.txt")
  EXISTING_TEXT=$(head -n 1 "$THISTEXT"); EXISTING_TEXT=${EXISTING_TEXT:0:20}
  ITEMSTRING+=("Text $i  :" "$i" 1 "$EXISTING_TEXT" "$i" 15 65 256)
done`

...will do the necessary. I do still wonder what the original REF variable was in prior answers and how it works, though!

Comment: @HowardRogers `man bash` is your friend. The bash manual is actually a surprisingly nice read, as manpages go. For this case, search the phrase "If the first character of parameter is an exclamation point" which should take you to the beginning of the parameter expansion section. Basically, you're right, it's a single level of indirection. If `onevar=1` and `oneref=onevar`, then "${!oneref}" expands to "${onevar}", which returns `1`. Another way to use references could be to declare one directly using `declare -n` (search `declare -n` in the bash manual for details on this)

Comment: I did read the man page actually. That's how I was able to say 'I *think* it's a Bash indirect parameter expansion'. But that meant nothing to me and still doesn't! If onevar=1 then why wouldn't you use '$onevar' in your code, rather than oneref=onevar and then use '$oneref'? The *point* of indirect expansions escapes me.  Even in your case, you set REF='variablestring'1 (and later to 'variablestring'2 etc), and then set iTEMSTRING to the indrectly expanded REF variable, where it presumably picks up the actual string value. Why not just say ITEMSTRING="Item$i"?

Comment: @HowardRogers Ah right. Sorry. That's because you cannot expand variables inside a the context of telling bash which variable you're trying to expand already; you cannot generate the varname on the spot inside an expansion. So, above, you cannot do "${Item$i}" to expand $i to 1 and thus try to access ${Item1}, bash will throw an error. You need to either pass `Item1` literally, or refer to that variable using indirection. Therefore I chose to create a variable REF=Item$i first, which sets $i from the for loop, and then used for indirection to expand ${Item1}, ${Item2}, etc in each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to show how much easier and comfortable the use of array is:

```
options=(
    --ok-label "Submit"
    --backtitle "Test input form"
    --title " Type information in "
    --form "" 12 95 0
)

items=(
    "Item 1  :"   1 1  "Item1"  1  15 65 256 
    "Item 2  :"   2 1  "Item2"  2  15 65 256 
    "Item 3  :"   3 1  "Item3"  3  15 65 256 
    "Item 4  :"   4 1  "Item4"  4  15 65 256 
)

dialog "${options[@]}" "${items[@]}"
```

Comment: This is more useful if a for loop isn't strictly necessary; otherwise you could `+=` as Philippe suggested above. But yes, indeed, bash arrays are lovely and very underrated. People often tend to reach straight for strings when an array would make things much simpler. :)